# Realizar busca dentro de objeto javascript e retornar valor

Tags: javascript, jquery, array, algoritmo-de-busca, objetos

eu preciso fazer uma busca dentro de um objeto javascript que me traga o sku de acordo com o tamanho e cor, vcs pode me dar uma luz?

Exemplo: Preciso inserir em uma variável o sku do produto que tenha a cor "Azul" e tamanho "Queen". Nesse caso seria o SKU 132

```
var produtos = {
skus:[{
    especificacao: {
        cor: "Azul",
        tamanho: "Queen"        
    },
    sku: 132
}, {
    especificacao: {
        cor: "Branco",
        tamanho: "Queen"
    },
    sku: 133
}]
};
```

Comment: Você pode utilizar a function filter dentro de outra function que recebe a cor e o tamanho. https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filtro

Comment: ⚠️ As duas respostas são boas, mas a outra não marcada com ✔️ é compatível também com o Internet Explorer (a que foi marcada não é).

Comment: obrigado pela informação. Como as duas funcionaram pra mim, vou aceitar sua sugestão.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Pode utilizar o [filter](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-PT/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter), seria algo do género:

```
var produtos = {
    skus: [
        {
            especificacao: {
                cor: "Azul",
                tamanho: "Queen"
            },
            sku: 132
        },{
            especificacao: {
                cor: "Branco",
                tamanho: "Queen"
            },
            sku: 133
        }
    ]
};

var list = produtos.skus.filter(function(item){
    return (item.especificacao.cor == 'Azul' && item.especificacao.tamanho == 'Queen');
});

console.log('Lista de Produtos: ', list);
```

Answer (score 4):

Ok, mas primeiro vamos criar um objeto válido, porque o declarado na pergunta não é.

```
var produtos = {
    skus:[{
        especificacao: {
            cor: "Azul",
            tamanho: "Queen"        
        },
        sku: 132
    }, {
        especificacao: {
            cor: "Branco",
            tamanho: "Queen"
        },
        sku: 133
    }]
};
```

Para pesquisar um objeto num array, você pode utilizar o método `find`. O método find recebe uma callback, e invoca essa callback passando por parâmetro cada objeto do seu array, basta então retornar `true` para quando o objeto atender seu critério.

```
var skuEncontrado = produtos.skus.find(sku => sku.especificacao.cor === 'Azul' && sku.especificacao.tamanho === 'Queen');
```